# SSL-VPN connection out into internet?

Tags: vpn, http, ssl, https

Is it possible for me to "rent" a web server, use a cisco AnyConnect client on my machine, create an SSL-VPN tunnel to the server I am renting and then use this to tunnel my internet connection onto the internet? Im having a hard time clarifying this on google....

Comment: How critical is the AnyConnect client requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) and/or [PrivateTunnel](https://www.privatetunnel.com/) provide the functionality you're looking for.